# Combining multiple observables in RxJava

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2

Let's say that I have 'n' data sources (REST APIs for instance):

```
Observable<List<DataItem>> source1 = api.source1();
Observable<List<DataItem>> source2 = api.source2();
Observable<List<DataItem>> source3 = api.source3();
...
Observable<List<DataItem>> sourcen = api.sourcen();
```

where 'n' is relatively small (~10)

What I want to do is to take all those sources, run them in parallel and receive `List<DataItem> list` containing all DataItems from all observables, but only when every network call is finished.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can do something like:

```
List<Observable<?>> obsList = Arrays.asList(source1, source2, source3, ...);

Observable.zip(obsList, ...
```

Comment: The suggestion I've seen to do this is to use something like:  `Observable<List<DataItem>> source1 = api.source1().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());` etc (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234152/how-can-i-make-this-rxjava-zip-to-run-in-parallel)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!